# rangeslider.js calling onchange() twice

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, range, phonegap

I am developing a phonegap application, and I am using [rangeslider](http://rangeslider.js.org/) to make the regular `<input type=range>` elements more visually appealing. However I ran into a problem with the following function which is called when the `onchange()` event fires:

```
function store_slider(){
    store_slider_val=document.getElementById("slider").value; //gets the value of the slider
    if(store_slider_val==100){
        //if slider is at 100 give a notification
        navigator.notification.confirm('Mark task as complete?',task_complete_handle,'Hey there!','YES,NO');
        function task_complete_handle(button){
            if(button==1){
                //do stuff
            }
            else{
                //set the slider to 90
                $('#slider').val(90).change();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the when the slider is at 100 the notification produced by `navigator.notification.confirm('Mark task as complete?',task_complete_handle,'Hey there!','YES,NO');` appears twice instead of once when I try the app in my phone(Appears only once when I run it in my laptop browser). When I don't use rangeslider the code works as expected.

How can I fix this issue? Rangeslider was a perfect and simple solution to making range inputs look better and I would really like to continue using this and not switch to another slider plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem only by completely removing rangeslider.js and using another plugin as it seems it is connected to the way rangeslider is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to only update the model if the value was different, this ensured that my model push to the back-end was only called once and not twice eg:

```
if (Model.value != $this.value) {
    Model.value = $this.value;
    PostToBackEnd();
}
```